# Mutliply characters in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception, index-error, stringindexoutofbounds

```
public class String_multiply {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = s.next();
        int len = str.length();
        int i=0;
        String c_s = new String();
        while(i<len) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))){
                char c =  str.charAt(i);
                c_s = String.valueOf(c);
                i++;
            }
            String n ="";
            while(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                n+=str.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            int inte =Integer.parseInt(n);
            System.out.print(c_s.repeat(inte));
        }
    }
}
```

*I don't know, where I went wrong. I get "String index out of range: 4" as error.*

Input:
a1b4c3

Output:
abbbbccc

Comment: is that your output, or your expected output? on what line do you get that error?

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, a `char` is incapable of representing most characters. Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this loop:

```
while(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    n+=str.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```

It tries to read a sequence of digits from the string, but it doesn't stop if `i` goes past the end of the string.

You must stop that loop if `i == len`:

```
while(i < len && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    n+=str.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```